# EPSON XP-225 printer says “offline”!

Tags: printer

I have an Epson XP 225 wireless printer, and every time I want to print something, it says "offline", and I have to go to control panel, delete the printer, and then add it again to print. After doing this process, it prints for couple hours, and then it gets offline again.
So, I'm running Windows 7 Proffesional on my ASUS computer, I updated the drivers, but I have another computer (ACER) running the same OS, and it PRINTS FINE with the same printer (EPSON XP 225 Wireless). 
I dont't know if the problem is in my computer, in my PC settings, or in the printer... The truth is that the printer was installed on the ACER PC FIRST, and then on the ASUS one... I dont't know if this is the reason why it doesn't print...
PLEASE HELP ME! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get to know here status of printer is offline or paused or can’t print. How can you make it ready to print again?

**1. Check status of your Printer**

• Open the devices and Printers Window.

• Move or hover your mouse over the icon that shows your product. You can see its status when a pop window will display.

**2. Change the status of Printer**

• Open devices and printers

• Right click on devices and printers, hold on your printer and select what you want to print.

• Click on Printer tab, uncheck or untick “Use Printer Offline” from the menu.

• If you find that printer is paused, unclick “Pause Printing” from the menu.